# Log4Net stops logging, how to recover?

Tags: c#, winforms, log4net

I have an issue with log4net (c#, WinForms) where it stops logging if there is a momentary glitch (like a network share becoming unreachable for a few seconds due to a VMware snapshot) and there seems to be no documented way to recover from such an interruption - it just stops logging until the application is restarted.  Version: v2.0.8

App.config section:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="K:\SomeApp-%property{log4net:HostName}-log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="40" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <errorHandler type="Acme.BusinessLayer.Log4NetErrorHandler" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <header value="[START] " />
        <footer value="[END] " />
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Note: I am using log4net.Core.IErrorHandler, so that I can dispatch an email about the issue.

**How can I resurrect/restart the logging when the log file is again accessible (which is usually only a matter of seconds)?**

Comment: Have you heard of Polly?

Comment: The log file path is not local to the system where application is running?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it is on a network drive (and it needs to be).

Comment: @JeremyThompson Yes, but I have never used it.  But unless there is a way to "resurrect" log4net's logging once it fails, I am not sure that Polly will be of much help.